# Unicode rails 3, how do i seed with unicode chars?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

What is the correct rails command to do

```
 "Català".to_html
```

Since when seeding any non ascii char will make the command crash (and i don't want to manually edit each text with the html representation).

> invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)

Thanks!

Comment: try adding # coding: UTF-8 more info here: https://github.com/goncalossilva/rails3_acts_as_paranoid/issues/19#comment_966836 and here https://github.com/siefca/i18n-inflector/issues/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `String`s don't have the correct encoding, where are you loading them from? If a ruby file, don't forget the magic comment `# encoding: utf-8`.